# How to use single json file to consume in alpacajs

Tags: javascript, alpacajs

I have created a simple form using alpacajs, as per the documentation provided by alpacajs.org we can use properties such as optionsSource, schemaSource, viewSource, dataSource for loading the external json files into our application. But what i need is i need to use only one json file for all these. I mean instead of using all these 3 different properties can i use only one parameter for loading the single json file which comes from the backend. please check my code below..

```
<html>
    <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My Little Alpaca Form</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"> </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//code.cloudcms.com/alpaca/1.5.22/bootstrap/alpaca.min.js"></script>
  <!-- typeahead.js https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.5/bloodhound.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.5/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link  href="//code.cloudcms.com/alpaca/1.5.22/bootstrap/alpaca.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="form1"></div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#form1").alpaca({
    "dataSource": "/fulfiller/connector-custom-data.json",
    "schemaSource": "/fulfiller/connector-custom-schema.json",
    "optionsSource": "/fulfiller/connector-custom-options.json",
    "viewSource": "/fulfiller/connector-custom-view.json",
     "view": {
        "parent": "bootstrap-edit",
        "layout": {
            "template": "threeColumnGridLayout",
            "bindings": {
                "requestedfor": "column-1",
                "location": "column-2",
                "shortdescription": "column-3",
                "description": "column-3",

            }
        },
        "templates": {
            "threeColumnGridLayout": '<div class="row">' + '{{#if options.label}}<h2>{{options.label}}</h2><span></span>{{/if}}' + '{{#if options.helper}}<p>{{options.helper}}</p>{{/if}}' + '<div id="column-1" class="col-md-6"> </div>' + '<div id="column-2" class="col-md-6"> </div>' + '<div id="column-3" class="col-md-12"> </div>' + '<div class="clear"></div>' + '</div>'
        }



    },
    "options": {
       "fields":  {
        "requestedfor": {
           "type": "text",
            "id": "requestedfor",
            "label": "*Requested For",
            "typeahead": {
                "config": {},
                "datasets": {
                    "type": "remote",
                    "displayKey": "value",
                    "templates": {},
                    "source": "http://www.alpacajs.org/data/tokenfield-ajax1.json"
                }
            }
        },
        "location": {
           "type": "text",
            "label": "*Location"
        },

     "shortdescription": {
             "type": "text",
            "label": "Short Description"
        },

    "description": {
           "type": "textarea",
           "rows": 5,
           "cols": 40,
          "label": "Description"             

        }


    },


    "form": {
            "attributes": {
                "action": "#",
                "method": "post"
            },
            "buttons": {
                "submit": {
                    "value": "Submit",
                   "class": "btn btn-default"
                }
            }
        }


}     

});
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So here in the above code i have used these urls for loading json data..

```
"dataSource": "/fulfiller/connector-custom-data.json"
"schemaSource": "/fulfiller/connector-custom-schema.json"
"optionsSource": "/fulfiller/connector-custom-options.json"
"viewSource": "/fulfiller/connector-custom-view.json"
```

So instead of using these 3 different properties can i use only one property like "oneSingleJSONSource": "oneJSONRemoteFile.json"

Can anybody provide inputs?

Answer (score 0):

For Alpaca to be inialized it must have a DOM element + a config object that contains the schema, options and other properties that Alpaca already knew in its core code, so in your case this is possible if you try to modify the alpaca core code... If your objective is only to optimize resource loading you can use only one json file that contains all the configuration and input them in the alpaca initialization `$(dom).alpaca(_json_data_from_loaded_file)`. And if you want to have only schema, options and view settings in on file you should divide the data loaded to 3 objects, 1 for schema, 1 for options and the last one for view settings.

Tell me if you want more details on achieving this.
I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Can you please explain more !